# Pandas Excel to DF throwing the unexpected keyword argument 'index' Error

Tags: python, pandas

Importing Excel into a Pandas DataFrame without the Index giving me this error

> TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

As far as I can see, I am not doing any thing wrong here

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Prod_User.xlsx', sheet_name='PROD', index=False)
print(df)
```

but getting the error! What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: what about using `index_col=0` instead of `index=False`?

Comment: The error says it already, remove `index=False`.

Comment: index parameter is not a valid argument for the `read_excel()` function, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: @Sauron TypeError for an argument that's not valid?

Comment: @wander95 I believe that's the Python default error; it can be interpreted as "the called function is not of correct type"

Answer (score 3):

The read_excel function in Pandas does not take an argument Index. You can specify the index column using the index_col argument. This can be used to specify the row labels. The default value for this argument is none so from your example I don't think you need to use it. If you have an index column that you are trying to omit from the excel sheet you could use the "usecols" argument to specify what columns you would like to read.
Please see *[Documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)* for more info!

Hope this helps!